# Gtk.Treeview get current row index in Python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

How to get index of current selected row in Gtk.TreeView in Python ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call [`gtk.TreeView.get_selection`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-selection) to get the current selection (`gtk.TreeSelection`). You can then call [`gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--get-selected) to get:

> a 2-tuple containing a reference to the gtk.TreeModel and a gtk.TreeIter pointing to the currently selected node.

The iter can be used on a `gtk.TreeModel` (which is obtained by calling [`gtk.TreeView.get_model`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-model). You can then use [`gtk.TreeModel.get_value`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html#method-gtktreemodel--get-value) to get any of the column values of the node at that position in the tree.

Answer (score 14):

The other answer is likely more useful in general. However, to answer the actual question posed by the OP, how to get the row index: assuming one row is selected, you can get it with:

```
index = treeview.get_selection().get_selected_rows()[1][0][0]
```

Comment: Thank! i spent hours looking for this! How one is suposed to know that ? its almost a haack :)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late, perhaps not so relevant, but if you have double clicked on the selected row you will get the row index as element of the TreePath tuple, like so

```
    def on_row_activated(self, treeview, path, column):
        model = self.treeview.get_model()
        tree_iter = model.get_iter(path)
        row = path[0]
        if tree_iter:
            # here you can get the values of the columns
```